Ajax post call to Controller method keeps saying 400 Bad Request
I am trying to make an Ajax post call to a method in my HomeController but I keep getting 400 Bad Request error.
This is the ajax call
$.ajax({
    url: '/home/findareacode',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({area: 'Ipswich'}),
    type: 'post',
    success: function (d) {
        alert("Response " + d);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error in finding areacode");
    }
});

And the method in my HomeController looks like below
[HttpPost]
public async Task<string> FindAreaCode(string area)
{
    string resp = area + " - 01473";
    return resp;
}

I have tried all the possibilities like setting dataType: 'json' and data: {area: "Ipswich"} and data: {"area": "Ipswich"} and contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' and using an object in the data, but in vain. But the same works for Get calls.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

The request is fairly simple - and it seems like it is a "search" method - have you considered passing area as a query string parameter and transforming this into a GET, or is it not a feasible solution for you? It definitely would simplify your request ajax-wise.

@PedroCosta the request works for GET just by changing the http method. The parameters needn't be changed. But I want this to work for POST only

Got it - I have a working pattern similar to yours, the difference being that in my ajax request I set 'contentType: application/json; charset=utf-8" and 'dataType: json'. You can try adding these additional parameters and see if it works for you

@PedroCosta As I mentioned I tried all these combinations. The answer was __RequestVerificationToken. I have explained it in my answer below

Your controller by default takes requests by url /home. But you're sending request to /home/findareacode
Maybe modify your HttpPost attribute like so:
[HttpPost("findareacode")]
public async Task<string> FindAreaCode(string area)
{
    string resp = area + " - 01473";
    return resp;
}


Not necessarily - i think that if the default route is {controller}/{action}/{id}, the default route should be as they have it. On top of that, if this was the issue the error code should be 404 as the route does not exist (or at least the OP has not shown such a route)

@PedroCosta is right. The casing doesn't matter. Also if you read the last line, I already mentioned that the same call works in GET

When you need to send data through the body of a POST request in ASP.NET Core, you should use the [FromBody] attribute in your controller method to bind the request body to a parameter
Modified controller code will look like following
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<string> FindAreaCode([FromBody]string area)
    {
        string resp = area + " - 01473";
        return resp;
    }

Hope this may help you.

The [FromBody] attribute may be required in this specific case, since area is a primitive type, but in general, the [FromBody] attribute is not required to handle POST requests. More details can be found in the documentation.

This doesn't resolve the problem @Subrahmanya

Tried using the RequestVerificationToken in the headers and it worked! The POST request would fail with 400 BadRequest even if such a request had no data (input parameters).
var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();

$.ajax({
    url: '/home/findareacode',
    data: {area: 'Ipswich'},
    headers: {'RequestVerificationToken': token},
    type: 'post',
    success: function (d) {
        alert("Response " + d);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error in finding areacode");
    }
});

The method in the HomeController should be modified to
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<string> FindAreaCode(string area)
{
    string resp = area + " - 01473";
    return resp;
}


Change your Ajax call signature and code action method signature as below
For AjAX:
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var comments = JSON.stringify(data)

    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        url: '/Home/FindAreaCode',
        data: { area: 'Ipswich' },
        success:
             function (d) 
             {
               alert("Response " + d);
             },
        error: 
            function () 
            {
               alert("error in finding areacode");
            }
    });
});

In CS Code file Remove [HttpPost]:
public async Task<ActionResult> FindAreaCode(string area)
{
    // Initialization.
    JsonResult result = new JsonResult();

    string resp = area + " - 01473";
    
    // Convert Result to JSON
    result = this.Json(resp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    return result;
}

Know that your action method name and parameter variable name is case sensitive for Ajax call

Action method name is not case sensitive
